# Get minted up and running with clean thesis

Tags: minted, cleanthesis

I am currently working with the [cleanthesis](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleanthesis?lang=en) package. Customizing this thing was ok so far, but now I encountered a real problem. While trying to use `minted`, I wasted a lot of time till I found out it works, but not with my current `cleanthesis` project. For testing purposes, I made a new file with this MNWE:

```
% **************************************************
% Document Class Definition
% **************************************************
\documentclass[%
paper=A4,                   % paper size --> A4 is default in Germany
twoside=true,               % onesite or twoside printing
openright,                  % doublepage cleaning ends up right side
parskip=full,               % spacing value / method for paragraphs
chapterprefix=true,         % prefix for chapter marks
11pt,                       % font size
headings=normal,            % size of headings
bibliography=totoc,         % include bib in toc
listof=totoc,               % include listof entries in toc
titlepage=on,               % own page for each title page
captions=tableabove,        % display table captions above the float env
draft=true,             % value for draft version
]{scrreprt}%

% **************************************************
% Debug LaTeX Information
% **************************************************
\listfiles
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % defines file's character encoding

% **************************************************
% Information and Commands for Reuse
% **************************************************
\newcommand{\thesisTitle}{}
\newcommand{\thesisName}{}
\newcommand{\thesisSubject}{Masterarbeit}
\newcommand{\thesisDate}{}
\newcommand{\thesisVersion}{0.1}

\newcommand{\thesisFirstReviewer}{}
\newcommand{\thesisFirstReviewerUniversity}{\protect{}}
\newcommand{\thesisFirstReviewerDepartment}{}

\newcommand{\thesisSecondReviewer}{ }
\newcommand{\thesisSecondReviewerUniversity}{\protect{}}
\newcommand{\thesisSecondReviewerDepartment}{\thesisFirstReviewerDepartment}

\newcommand{\thesisFirstSupervisor}{}
\newcommand{\thesisSecondSupervisor}{}

\newcommand{\thesisUniversity}{\protect{Universität Bielefeld}}
\newcommand{\thesisUniversityDepartment}{Technische Fakultät}
\newcommand{\thesisUniversityInstitute}{}
\newcommand{\thesisUniversityGroup}{\thesisFirstReviewerDepartment}
\newcommand{\thesisUniversityCity}{Bielefeld}
\newcommand{\thesisUniversityStreetAddress}{}
\newcommand{\thesisUniversityPostalCode}{33615 Bielefeld}

% **************************************************
% Load and Configure Packages
% **************************************************


\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % babel system, adjust the language of the content
\usepackage[                    % clean thesis style
figuresep=colon,%
sansserif=false,%
hangfigurecaption=true,%
hangsubsection=true,%
colorize=full,%
colortheme=bluemagenta,%
bibsys=biber,%
bibfile=refs,%
bibstyle=numeric,%
]{cleanthesis}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{c}
int main() {
printf("hello, world");
return 0;
}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas what could cause this problem?

Comment: Rather than a working example with `article`, a non working one with `cleanthesis` would be better.

Comment: You're right, I fixed this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're passing `draft=true` to `\documentclass`, so it is a global option; also `minted` understands and accepts it.

Solution:

```
\usepackage[draft=false]{minted}
```